# Define the queue condition for Heapq Python

Tags: python, list, queue, heap

I have lists :

```
mylist = [[3, "A", "X", "xyz", 0.93243],[43, "C", "X", "zyx", 0.23243],[13, "B", "X", "xyz", 0.43243]]

heapq.heapify(mylist)
mylist
[[3, 'A', 'X', 'xyz', 0.93243],
 [43, 'C', 'X', 'zyx', 0.23243],
 [13, 'B', 'X', 'xyz', 0.43243]]
```

When I want to pop list by using `heapq.heappop(mylist)`.
First item that will be popped is `[3, 'A', 'X', 'xyz', 0.93243]`. I guess, it is because the first value (`3`) in the item list is the lowest.

Is it possible If I want to use the last value, `index[4]` as the basis. So the popping item is based on the last element in the list?

Expected output when I want to pop item, the first item will be popped is `[43, 'C', 'X', 'zyx', 0.23243]` because the `index[4]` has lowest value which is `0.23243`

Answer (score 1):

Your lists need to be objects that implement a custom cmp function like so:

```
class MyObject():
...     
...     def __cmp__(self, other):
...         return cmp(self.val, other.val)
...
```

Comment: could you please give me an example using my list above. I am not clearly understand